# Reading config.js in Python

Tags: javascript, python, config

I'm working in a project using both javascript and python. My python code has to be able to read a config.js file and get from there IP adresses, passwords, hosts....
**I am not able to modify in any way the config.js file.**

I've tried using slimit but it mixes some of the field so I can't properly acces my data. It might be because some of the data is really nested and there is a lot of comments through the config.js file.

The config file looks like this (but is actually a lot longer)

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    someconfig: {
        File: {
            path: '/some/path', // comment
            some_number: 50, // comment
        },
        Syslog: {
            path: '/some/other/path', // comment
            localhost: 'localhost', //comment
            app_name: 'somename', // comment
        },
        /**
        * some really
        * long
        * long
        * comment
        */
    },

    db: {
        mongoose: "5.0",
        servers: [{
            host: '1.1.1.1'
        }],
        database: 'somebase',  // comment
        user: 'myUserName',  //comment
        pass: 'myPassword',  // comment

        // some_comment

        config: {
            // some comment
            autoIndex: false
        },

        // lots of
        // comments
        // several lines

        someconfig: {
            // comment
            somevariable: "variable",
            anothervariable: "reallylongstring_aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        },
    },

    anotherconfig: {
        very_nested: [{
            host: '1.1.1.1'
        }],
        database: 'anotherdatabase', // comment
        user: 'myUserName', // comment
        pass: 'myPassword', // comment
    },


};
```

and the code I've tried is this

```py
from slimit.parser import Parser

parser = Parser()
tree = parser.parse(open(r'C:\path\to\config copy.js').read())
fields = {getattr(node.left, 'value', ''): getattr(node.right, 'value', '')
          for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree)
          if isinstance(node, ast.Assign)}

print (fields)
```

But it returns this

```
{'': '', 'someconfig': '', 'File': '', 'path': "'/some/other/path'", 'some_number': '50', 'Syslog': '',
 'localhost': "'localhost'", 'app_name': "'somename'", 'db': '', 'mongoose': '"5.0"',
 'servers': '', 'host': "'1.1.1.1'", 'database': "'anotherdatabase'",
 'user': "'myUserName'", 'pass': "'myPassword'", 'config': '', 'autoIndex': 'false', 'somevariable': '"variable"',
 'anothervariable': '"reallylongstring_aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"',
 'anotherconfig': '', 'very_nested': ''}
```

as you can see it mixed the two database name ('somebase' is not there, only 'anotherbase')

Any idea on how to get my data correctly?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's useful to utilize the NodeVisitor here.

Instead, recursively walk the entire AST and build a nested dict from all the items of interest. As a minimal implementation, to be extended as you see fit:

```
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit import ast

parser = Parser()

with open(r'config.js', encoding='utf8') as js:
    tree = parser.parse(js.read())

def walk(node):
    if not isinstance(node, ast.Node): 
        return
    elif isinstance(node, ast.Program):
        # the Program node itself becomes a dict of its contained assignments
        items = [walk(child) for child in node.children()]
        # assignments can be recognized by the fact that they are (name, value) tuples
        return dict(i[0] for i in items if isinstance(i[0], tuple))
    elif isinstance(node, ast.Assign):
        # an Assignment node becomes a (name, value) tuple
        return walk(node.left), walk(node.right)
    elif isinstance(node, ast.DotAccessor):
        # a DotAccessor node becomes a string.joined.with.dots
        return '.'.join(walk(child) for child in node.children())
    elif isinstance(node, ast.Object):
        # an Object node becomes a dict
        return dict(walk(child) for child in node.children())
    elif isinstance(node, ast.Array):
        # an Array node becomes a list
        return list(walk(child) for child in node.children())
    elif isinstance(node, (ast.Identifier, ast.String, ast.Number, ast.Boolean)):
        # Indentifiers and primitives give their native values
        return node.value       
    return [walk(child) for child in node.children()]

result = walk(tree)
print(result)
```

which produces a neatly nested object graph that should be easy to handle:

```
{
    'module.exports': {
        'someconfig': {
            'File': {
                'path': "'/some/path'",
                'some_number': '50'
            },
            'Syslog': {
                'path': "'/some/other/path'",
                'localhost': "'localhost'",
                'app_name': "'somename'"
            }
        },
        'db': {
            'mongoose': '"5.0"',
            'servers': [{'host': "'1.1.1.1'"}],
            'database': "'somebase'",
            'user': "'myUserName'",
            'pass': "'myPassword'",
            'config': {'autoIndex': 'false'},
            'someconfig': {
                'somevariable': '"variable"',
                'anothervariable': '"reallylongstring_aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"'
            }
        },
        'anotherconfig': {
            'very_nested': [{'host': "'1.1.1.1'"}],
            'database': "'anotherdatabase'",
            'user': "'myUserName'",
            'pass': "'myPassword'"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aude It's still a bit messy and less elegant than I'd like it to be. I'll try to clean it up some more later today. Also, there probably is a way to turn this into a visitor pattern, but simple recursion seemed to be the quickest approach to me.

Comment: I left a comment to thank you that somehow disapeared. Anyway thanks a lot for your help, and it does exactly what I wanted it to do. If you manage to make it even cleaner that would be impressive, it looks elgant as it is, to me at least. I didn't know you could call a function within itself like you do with walk:  `walk(child, context)` that is the only thing that seems strange.

Comment: @Aude That's called recursion. Yeah, there is a certain effort going on to "clean up" comments, and "thank you" type comments often are shot down, likely by some sort of algorithm, but also moderators do it. I can't say that I agree to this, but there is not a whole lot I can do about it.

Comment: @Aude I've polished the code some more, it's getting there. I'm sure there's still more to improve.

Comment: it's very neat now. I like how you comment each step :)